# why this interesting result with this mysql query...?

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

this is my table.

```
mysql> desc products;
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default                              | Extra |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
| productCode        | varchar(15) | NO   | PRI | NULL                                 |       |
| productName        | varchar(70) | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| productUrl         | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL                                 |       |
| productLine        | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| productScale       | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| productVendor      | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| productDescription | text        | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| quantityInStock    | smallint(6) | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| buyPrice           | double      | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| MSRP               | double      | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| Image              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | phpGridx/SampleImages/motorcycle.jpg |       |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

when I tried the below query ..?

```
mysql> select productVendor,count(productCode) from products order by productCode;
+-----------------+--------------------+
| productVendor   | count(productCode) |
+-----------------+--------------------+
| Min Lin Diecast |                110 |
+-----------------+--------------------+
```

why it is displayed 'Min Lin Diecast'. I have about 11 other productVendors in my table. Why it took that, The total row count is 110 it is okay, But I dont understand Why it displayed that Vendor especially. (it is not the first record even).

can any body explain me why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT productVendor,count(productCode) 
FROM products 
GROUP BY productVendor
ORDER BY productCode;
```

Comment: I know it does not have group by...!  but let me know why it displayed that Product vendoronly..!

Comment: Because you have used COUNT function It will give you the count and check **Min Lin Diecast** is the first entry of your select output when you ordering data by product code. So it will resturn first row of query with count of data

Comment: Got it yaar...! Thank you saharsh..!

Comment: but onething is the flaw in this result, as the count is not related to that product vendor, It has to give a null value as productVendor column or it should not accept right?? it is a wrong result for perfectly wrong query ,..I feel

Comment: No, mysql gives count of all tows tabl if you not specify group by clause irrespective of what is the productvendor. So you have to specify Group by clause if you want count for eeach product vendor

Answer (score 3):

because you have no `GROUP BY` clause causing it to have only 1 record return.

```
select productVendor,count(productCode) 
from products 
GROUP BY productVendor
order by productCode
```

If you enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in mysql, your query will not execute.

Comment: I understood but let me know why it displayed that Product vendor

Comment: if you run this query `SELECT productCode, productVendor from products  ORDER BY productCode ASC`, what will be the first record?

Comment: It is the first query. But I feel, ...it is a wrong result for a perfectly wrong query..! what do you say??

Comment: the query is not wrong. it's just that you have not enabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in you server. so the server executes the query by counting all records in your table and displaying the first record according to which field you have set an index, so in this case, the `Min Lin Diecast`

Answer (score 0):

As you are not adding GROUP BY clause in the query and in the SELECT statement you have two column productVendor and productCode, my question is if you want to know just count of  productCode then why you are selecting productVendor column, because always productVendor value will be the first value of that column.

So if you want count of all productCode , productVendor wise you should use this GROUP BY clause

```
     SELECT productVendor,count(productCode) 
     FROM   products 
     GROUP BY productVendor
     ORDER BY productCode
```